# Trying to access variable from other object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to give ammo to the player when he kills an enemy. I'm trying to use GetComponent, but I keep getting the error ": error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 'thro'. Did you intend to invoke the method?" on this line:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class collision : MonoBehaviour
{
 public int cardno = 13;
 public GameObject deck;
 thro deck_script;

 void OnCollisionEnter (Collision cl)
 {
  if(cl.collider.tag == "iscard")
  {
   int cardran = Random.Range(1,14);
   Debug.Log(cardran);
   *deck_script = deck.GetComponent<thro>;*
   if (cardran == cardno)
   {
    
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("kil");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deck_script = deck.GetComponent<thro>;
```

Is not the correct syntax for calling a function. Try:

```
deck_script = deck.GetComponent<thro>();
```

See documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html